# Express res.sendfile throwing forbidden error

Tags: node.js, express

I have this code:

```
res.sendfile( '../../temp/index.html' )
```

However, it throws this error:

```
Error: Forbidden
at SendStream.error (/Users/Oliver/Development/Personal/Reader/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:145:16)
at SendStream.pipe (/Users/Oliver/Development/Personal/Reader/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:307:39)
at ServerResponse.res.sendfile (/Users/Oliver/Development/Personal/Reader/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:339:8)
at exports.boot (/Users/Oliver/Development/Personal/Reader/server/config/routes.js:18:9)
at callbacks (/Users/Oliver/Development/Personal/Reader/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
at param (/Users/Oliver/Development/Personal/Reader/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
at pass (/Users/Oliver/Development/Personal/Reader/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
at Router._dispatch (/Users/Oliver/Development/Personal/Reader/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
at Object.router (/Users/Oliver/Development/Personal/Reader/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
at next (/Users/Oliver/Development/Personal/Reader/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
```

Can anyone tell me why this might be?

Comment: I believe it's because of the relative path; the "../" is considered malicious.  Resolve the local path first, then call `res.sendfile`

Comment: How do you resolve the local path?

Comment: `path.resolve` should do what you need.

Comment: That did it. Want to past that as an answer?

Answer (score 344, accepted):

I believe it's because of the relative path; the "../" is considered malicious. Resolve the local path first, then call `res.sendfile`.  You can resolve the path with `path.resolve` beforehand.

```
var path = require('path');
res.sendFile(path.resolve('temp/index.html'));
```

Comment: more details would be handy here for newbies like me

Comment: Express considers relative paths in `sendfile` as bad.  Unless you specify the `root` directory parameter, as seen here: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1465

Comment: var path = require('path');

Comment: yeah the final codE!!

Comment: @MattHarrison ES6 update, for packages imports, `const` is preferred over `var`

Comment: The `resolve` will resolve the relative path and create an absolute path, that then will be treated as the 'root' - if the strings received by `resolve` doesn't form an absolute path, the path from the current directory is used. [Reference](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths).

Answer (score 45):

This answer gathers together the info from the other answers/comments.

It depends whether you want to include something relative to the process working directory (cwd) or the file directory. Both use the `path.resolve` function (put `var path = require('path')` at the top of the file.

- relative to cwd: `path.resolve('../../some/path/to/file.txt');`
- relative to file: `path.resolve(__dirname+'../../some/path/to/file.txt');`

From reading the link from @Joe's comment, it sounds like relative paths are a security risk if you accept user input for the path (e.g. `sendfile('../.ssh/id_rsa')` might be a hacker's first try).

Comment: AS a newbie I want to know how hacker scenario came here?

Comment: If you accidentally allow the user to input the path of the file they want to download, they could download any file on your system (I gave the example of a ssh private key - which would give them the ability to pretend to be your PC (man-in-the-middle etc)). Having the .. restriction disallows this possibility as only files from the website can be accessed.

Answer (score 35):

The [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) suggests doing it a different way, and in my opinion it makes more sense later than the current solution.

`res.sendFile('index.html', {root: './temp'});`

The root option seems to set `./` as the root directory of your project. So I cannot fully tell where you file is in relation to the project root, but if your temp folder is there, you can set `./temp` as the root for the file you're sending.

Comment: This is true, but it uses sendFile (capital F, supported by Express v4.8.0 onwards) instead of the older sendfile the OP was using. Just saying... =]

Comment: Ahh... good catch.  I didn't notice this small difference. I also wonder if the selected answer works not because it uses `.sendfile` but because it relies on something else completely (path).

Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Simple and eficient. Thank you! This worked for me perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

Also, you can use `path.join`

```js
const path = require("path");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let indexPath = path.join(__dirname, "../public/index.html");
  res.sendFile(indexPath);
});
```