# Node express routing sendfile fails depending on file location

Tags: node.js, express, pushstate, sendfile

I have a directory structure for a restful express service + Backbone client with **pushState** enabled like this (client code in `public/`)

```
app.js
lib/routes.js
-- public/
   -- index.html
```

I set up `/public` to be a static directory in `app.configure`:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

This already works off the bat if the index is visited first.

Then when I directly visit a route other than homepage I ensure to redirect to the `index.html`. This works perfectly fine in `app.js`, **but if I try and put this in `lib/routes.js` I get a Forbidden error**:

From `app.js` works fine:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

From `lib/routes.js`:

```
res.sendfile(__dirname + '../public/index.html');
```

Gives me:

```
Error: Forbidden
        at SendStream.error (/Users/*****/Sites/myproject/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:145:16)
        at SendStream.pipe (/Users/*****/Sites/myproject/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:307:39)
        at ServerResponse.res.sendfile (/Users/*****/Sites/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:345:8)
        at /Users/*****/Sites/myproject/lib/routes.js:8:7
        at callbacks (/Users/*****/Sites/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
        at param (/Users/*****/Sites/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
        at pass (/Users/*****/Sites/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
        at Router._dispatch (/Users/*****/Sites/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
        at Object.router (/Users/*****/Sites/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
        at next (/Users/*****/Sites/myproject/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
```

If I simply try:

```
res.sendfile('/public/index.html');
```

It can't find the file and I get:

```
Error: ENOENT, stat '/public/index.html'
```

To summarise how can I use `sendFile` and pass in `public/index.html` from `lib/routes.js` without getting a Forbidden error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Express res.sendfile throwing forbidden error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594121/express-res-sendfile-throwing-forbidden-error)

Comment: It's because of the relative path in `../public/index.html`.  See the dupe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks @Joe. For completeness since the dupe isn't very clear and trying various relative pathing including trying `{root: 'somepath'}` as 2nd param didn't work this is what I did:

```
var path = require('path');
...
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(path.resolve('public/index.html'));
});
```

Even though that is in the `lib/` directory it resolved using the base directory, to re-reiterate relative resolving didn't work for me but there may be some way of doing it.