# res.sendFile absolute path

Tags: node.js, express, path

If I do a

```
res.sendfile('public/index1.html');
```

then I get a server console warning

> express deprecated `res.sendfile`: Use `res.sendFile` instead

but it works fine on the client side.

But when I change it to

```
res.sendFile('public/index1.html');
```

I get an error

> TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to `res.sendFile`

and `index1.html` is not rendered.

I am unable to figure out what the absolute path is. I have `public` directory at the same level as `server.js`. I am doing the `res.sendFile` from with `server.js`. I have also declared `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Adding my directory structure:

```
/Users/sj/test/
....app/
........models/
....public/
........index1.html
```

What is the absolute path to be specified here ?

I'm using Express 4.x.

Comment: If you're using the `express.static` middleware to serve your public directory, why do you need `res.sendFile` to send `public/index1.html`?

Comment: I'm calling `res.sendFile` from within `app.get('/', function(req, res){res.sendFile("...")})` to send it on demand.

Answer (score 367, accepted):

The `express.static` middleware is separate from `res.sendFile`, so initializing it with an absolute path to your `public` directory won't do anything to `res.sendFile`.  You need to use an absolute path directly with `res.sendFile`. There are two simple ways to do it:

1. `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'index1.html'));`
2. `res.sendFile('index1.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../public') });`

***Note:** `__dirname` returns the directory that the currently executing script is in. In your case, it looks like `server.js` is in `app/`. So, to get to `public`, you'll need back out one level first: `../public/index1.html`.*

***Note:** [`path` is a built-in module](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html) that needs to be `require`d for the above code to work: `var path = require('path');`*

Comment: `res.sendFile('../public/index.html', {root: __dirname});` also works and it's shorter

Comment: Working with express and webstorm ide: got no error in `console.log(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'));` but `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'));` work only with  `var path = require('path');`

Comment: Is there no way to pre-define the absolute path so it can be used in sendFile ?

Comment: `res.sendFile('../public/index.html', {root: __dirname});` doesn't work (anymore), as it returns 403 Forbidden due to going above the root. Do `res.sendFile('public/index.html', {root: path.dirname(__dirname)});` instead.

Comment: @eranotzap and shouldn't `app.use(express.static('public'))` be a lookup path in the first place?

Answer (score 62):

Just try this instead:

```
res.sendFile('public/index1.html' , { root : __dirname});
```

This worked for me.
the root:__dirname will take the address where server.js is in the above example and then to get to the index1.html ( in this case) the returned path is to get to the directory where public folder is.

Comment: Why is this option not documented?

Answer (score 12):

An alternative that hasn't been listed yet that worked for me is simply using `path.resolve` with either separate strings or just one with the whole path:

```
// comma separated
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile( path.resolve('src', 'app', 'index.html') );
});
```

Or

```
// just one string with the path
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile( path.resolve('src/app/index.html') );
});
```

(Node v6.10.0)

Idea sourced from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14594282/6189078

Answer (score 10):

```
res.sendFile( __dirname + "/public/" + "index1.html" );
```

where `__dirname` will manage the name of the directory that the currently executing script ( `server.js` ) resides in.

Comment: This solution was pretty straight forward Thanks for the help .. I wonder why people recommend to use the 'path' package to do the same.

Comment: @TheThird i guess, using `path` makes it os-independent.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the other answers, this is a simple example of how to accomplish the most common requirement:

```
const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public')) // relative path of client-side code
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname })
})
app.listen(process.env.PORT)
```

This also doubles as a simple way to [respond with index.html on every request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41696045/272372), because I'm using a star `*` to catch all files that weren't found in your static (public) directory; which is the most common use case for web-apps. Change to `/` to return the index only in the root path.

Comment: Nice. Nice and succinct.

Answer (score 6):

`process.cwd()` returns the absolute path of your project.

Then :

```
res.sendFile( `${process.cwd()}/public/index1.html` );
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried this and it worked.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use send instead of sendFile so you wont face with error!
this works will help you!

```
fs.readFile('public/index1.html',(err,data)=>{
if(err){
  consol.log(err);
}else {
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
```

for telling browser that your response is type of PDF

```
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='your_file_name_for_client.pdf');
```

if you want that file open immediately on the same page after user download it.write 'inline' instead attachment in above code.

```
res.send(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this by writing less code.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

Comment: This generates "TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set this up once and use it everywhere, just configure your own middleware. When you are setting up your app, use the following to define a new function on the response object:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.show = (name) => {
    res.sendFile(`/public/${name}`, {root: __dirname});
  };
  next();
});
```

Then use it as follows:

```
app.get('/demo', (req, res) => {
  res.show("index1.html");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

```
res.sendFile("./public/filename.ext", { root: "./" });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Node.Js and had the same problem... I solved just adding a '/' in the beggining of every script and link to an css static file.

**Before:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**After:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: You would have to set up the express static server for this to work

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'./path_to_file_from_current_directory'));
```