# `express.js` throw error on sending static file

Tags: express

I am using express version : `express@4.12.3`

And while supplying the static html i use the following:

```
app

    .get('*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile('public/main.html');
    })
```

But I am getting error as :

```
TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
```

Instead if i use the `res.sendfile` - works but i am getting error from `cmd` saying to use `sendFile` - what else i do? what is the issue here?

any one guide me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [res.sendFile absolute path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463423/res-sendfile-absolute-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead of writing the relative path :

```
    res.sendFile(__dirname +'/public/main.html');
```