# routerLink not working with AOT build

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, webpack-2, angular2-aot

The routerLink works fine when I do a normal JIT build. But when I try to do an AOT build router link does not redirect to the specified route.

My html code

```
<ul id="submenu" class="lista-menu aln-centro">
     <li><a 
        routerLinkActive='active'
        routerLink='home'
     >Home</a></li>
     <li><a 
        routerLinkActive='active'
        routerLink='products'
    >Products</a></li>
    <li><a 
        routerLinkActive='active'
        routerLink='about'
    >About</a></li>
    <li><a 
        routerLinkActive='active'
        routerLink='contacts'
    >Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Since the routing is working in the JIT build therefore I think either I have missed something in my webpack build process or this is a bug in the the `@angular/router` module, more likely the first one.

Link to git repo with the complete code:
https://github.com/rachitbhasin/ng2-webpack-aot

Node version: 6.4.0 or greater.

Install dependencies:
`npm install`

Run DEV/JIT build: `npm run start`

Run AOT build: `npm run build`

Run server after AOT build: `npm run server`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is not the Angular router forwarding but the http server, which can not give a suitable response for the request.

Simply configure your http server to **always return the index.html** file.

See this example with [Express](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41696045/7980937).