# node-http-server module to respond with index.html to any request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, node-modules, node-http-proxy

I have installed a `node-http-server` module. I launch it from `myDir` on localhost port 8000. In `myDir` I have index.html.
If I request (from the browser) `http://localhost:8000/` I get `index.html`, which is OK and good.

If I request though `http://localhost:8000/anything` I do not get any response from the server.

Here's the Code I used (app.js):

```
const server=require('node-http-server');
var fs = require("fs");
var config = new server.Config;
config.root=__dirname;
config.server.index='index.html';

function getReq(req, res, body,enc) {
    console.log("got rewq");
    var content = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf8');
    body.value = content;

}
server.deploy({port:8000});
```

I found that the same question asked in this link: [node http-server to respond with index.html to any request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744309/node-http-server-to-respond-with-index-html-to-any-request/39744827#39744827) . But it was for `http-server` module. I am using `node-http-server` module.
I read documentation in https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-http-server. But can't find any suitable solutions. Help me with Some solutions.

Comment: If you intend to only respond with your index.html, why do you need anything more that vanilla node? The getting started example has this behavior. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/

Comment: @JDunken, I have linked a JS in index.html. In the JS, there are various routers. The index.html gets me to home page. In home page, I have a top navigation bar which route to several pages. It was working great and it was navigating properly. But when I type a certain url `http://localhost:8000/anything` in the address bar, I do not get any response from the server. it shows 404.

Comment: have you tried `server.onRequest=getReq;` before `server.deploy()`? https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-http-server#onrequest

Answer (score 0):

To start exploring your problem i would look at your code first.

```
const server=require('node-http-server');
var fs = require("fs");
var config = new server.Config;
config.root=__dirname;
config.server.index='index.html';

function getReq(req, res, body,enc) {
    console.log("got rewq");
    var content = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf8');
    body.value = content;

}
server.deploy({port:8000});
```

GetReq() function clearly should do what you expect it to do but i dont see where you actually supply node-http-server witht his function to be called as a callback. Now lets fix your code.

```
const server=require('node-http-server');
var fs = require("fs");
var config = new server.Config;
config.root=__dirname;
config.server.index='index.html';

function getReq(req, res, body,enc) {
    console.log("got rewq");
    var content = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf8');
    body.value = content;

}
server.deploy({port:8000}, getReq);
```

In short you didnt read documentation for the module, you need to pass your callback function as an option to deploy method. `server.deploy({port:8000}, getReq);`