# Getting type error while redirecting to the page using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting one error while trying to display the html page using Node.js. I am providing error below.

```
TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
   at ServerResponse.sendFile (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:404:11)
   at /opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/server.js:40:6
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at next (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at /opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
   at Function.process_params (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at next (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at Immediate.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/express-session/index.js:473:7)
```

I am providing my code below.

```
var express=require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var http=require('http');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongo = require('mongojs');
var session = require('express-session');
var multer  = require('multer')
var app=module.exports=express();
var server=http.Server(app);
var port=8989;
var admin=require('./route/route.js');
var api=require('./api/api.js');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                     // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json())    // parse application/json
app.use(methodOverride());                  // simulate DELETE and PUT
app.use(session({secret: 'FGDPlexel',resave: true,saveUninitialized: true}));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})
app.get('/api/users/reset',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('views/reset.html');
})
server.listen(port);
```

When I am typing the url `http://localhost:8989/api/users/reset?id=5981b48654d471000459208e` I am getting the above error. My folder structure is given below.

```
fgdp(root folder)
 -> public
     ->views
     ->controller

 server.js
```

My HTML page is present inside the `views` folder.

Comment: please check if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463423/res-sendfile-absolute-path

Comment: I think here you can find your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463423/res-sendfile-absolute-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not specifying the absolute path, please resolve it. Modify your route request as

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/views', 'index.html'));
});
app.get('/api/users/reset',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/views', 'reset.html'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Console log `__dirname + '/index.html'` to check if the path to index.hmtl is correct or not.

Secondly, `res.sendFile('views/reset.html');` this won't work. It clearly says use absolute path. `views/reset.html` is a relative path. use [path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html) with `__dirname` to get absolute path.