# how to correct issue with nodejs with react app not loading content properly related to Content Security Policy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm currently having issues with my code not deploying on heroku with a "Cannot GET /" message, when I seem to have no issues when running the server on my laptop.  I'm not sure if it's a path issue as my console issued the following error: Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src https://mvpauto.herokuapp.com”). Source: ;(function installGlobalHook(window) {

I have not set up my code to tinker with my response object headers to set the CSP, nor do I have any middleware running outside of body-parser, which I also tried to disable in my debugging to no avail.  My headers are as follows:

```
Server  Cowboy
Connection  keep-alive
X-Powered-By    Express
Content-Security-Policy default-src 'self'
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length  139
Date    Sun, 01 Oct 2017 04:12:05 GMT
Via 1.1 vegur


Request headers (364 B) 
Host    
mvpauto.herokuapp.com
User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
Accept      text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language     en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding     gzip, deflate, br
DNT     1
Connection      keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests       1
Cache-Control       max-age=0
```

These are the headers when running locally successfully using "heroku local"

```
X-Powered-By        Express
Accept-Ranges       bytes
Cache-Control       public, max-age=0
Last-Modified       Sun, 01 Oct 2017 03:26:11 GMT
ETag        W/"17f-15ed5f847af"
Date        Sun, 01 Oct 2017 04:29:45 GMT
Connection      keep-alive

Request headers (439 B) 
Host        localhost:5000
User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
Accept    text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language     en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding     gzip, deflate
DNT     1
Connection      keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests       1
If-Modified-Since       Sun, 01 Oct 2017 03:26:11 GMT
If-None-Match       W/"17f-15ed5f847af"
Cache-Control       max-age=0
```

And then my index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const db = require(__dirname + '/../database');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../client/dist')));
const router = require('./routes');    
app.use('/', router);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/../client/dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Listening on port ' + port));
```

I don't have any get request handlers for my root('/') endpoint, since on the client side, a get request is submitted to the '/todos' endpoint on load.  I tried adding a '/' handler and having get requests to root result in a res.sendFile('index.html'), which in turn results in a "Forbidden" message.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The issue might be with the server.js code.

Comment: thanks, Krisha. I've added the server.js code as well as some additional remarks regarding my troubleshooting.

Comment: I hope the solutions mentioned here would help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463423/res-sendfile-absolute-path

Comment: thank you. I just found the issue, which was that I had my server.js file in a separate server folder in the root of the app repo, and heroku, from what I gathered from observation, as I can't find any of this in their documentation nor discussed online elsewhere.  This becomes especially problematic when trying to access my client files which sit in a folder that is a sibling of the server dir.

Comment: Congratuation @Quilty Kim  on finding the solution and thanks for posting your finding

Answer (score 0):

I just found the issue, which was that I had my server.js file in a separate server folder in the root of the app repo.  This becomes especially problematic when trying to access my client files which sit in a folder that is a sibling of the server dir, as the only way to traverse to the client directory is through passing through the shared parent, which I don't have access to.  This is all gathered from observation and having run 'heroku run ls ~', as I can't find any of this in their documentation nor discussed online elsewhere.