# Different Path for Serving Static HTML files in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Just a quick question. Say I have 2 different static HTML files that I want to serve in Express, `index.html` and `contact.html`. I've been fiddling around and I currently use this barebone Express code to serve them:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('/index.html');
});

app.get('/contact', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/contact.html');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('runnning on port 3000')
});
```

Question is, I tried to serve `contact.html` using

```
app.get('/contact', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/contact.html');
});
```

but it always resort to the root directory instead of the public directory. OTOH, I can server `index.html` just fine without having to explicitly adding `/public` in the response.

Can anybody point me what's the cause for that?

Thanks.

Comment: It will help you I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463423/res-sendfile-absolute-path

Comment: FYI: with debugging you'll see that `app.get('/', function (req, res) {` doesn't get called when you request `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: While it is possible to serve static files with node.js, it is always better to use nginx for it.

Answer (score 1):

For the given file structure:

```
yourapp
 |-- contact.html
 |-- index.html
 `-- server.js
```

The following code would work just fine:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/contact', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/contact.html');
});
```

Assuming both `index.html` and `contact.html` have read access.

Remember, `sendFile` requires an **absolute path** and `__dirname` refers to **your app directory**. Make sure you give references according to your file location.