# unable to send data from express.js to html in template

Tags: node.js, express

server.js

```
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
let path = require('path');
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'),{name:"srk"})
})
```

index.html

```
<%= name %>
```

In some website i found this way to send data from express to html.
but i am getting <%= name %> instead of actual data.
please have a look into it

Comment: check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25463996)

Comment: but ther is only rendering available. i wants to send data to html

Answer (score 0):

You should use res.render( view, { options } ) instead i.e

- You need a view engine such as ejs, and then set it in your code
- Create views folder and point express to the folder
- Rename your index.html file to index.ejs and move it to your newly created views folder

  `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

  `app.set('views', <views folder url>);`

Then in your app.get(), use

```
`res.render('index.ejs', {
    name: "srk"
}`
```

if you don't already have ejs, run `npm install --save ejs`

Comment: Yes, the code in ejs file is html. The only difference is the file extension .ejs instead of .html