# unexpected token / in json at position 0 Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to send pdf file path.
I have to send below pdf path to open in a new window

res.send(__dirname + '/../assets/public/abc.pdf)Added code snippet

[CLICK HERE FOR DETAILED CODE SNIPPET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghaKL.png)

Comment: Please post your code in text rather than in a link or image.

Answer (score 0):

`res.send` expects the content to be sent. You're sending a path. If you want to send a document, use [res.sendFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463423/res-sendfile-absolute-path) instead.

Check out the docs for [res.send](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) and notice that you can only use it to send content and not paths.

Also read the docs for [res.sendFile](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile).