# how I can prevent res.sendFile changing file path?

Tags: node.js

I'm using node.js and want to send file to the frontend. So I specified the direct path to my file like:
path = "c:/app/A"
and when I run res.sendFile(path, fileName);
I'm getting the Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/projects/c:/app/A'
How I can disable this auto path adding "/home/projects" part?
I want to download file that is not in my project folder with my code. File is in my computer in different folder.

Comment: if you can provide your project directory structure and in which file you are executing res.sendFile

Comment: please submit your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [res.sendFile absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463423/res-sendfile-absolute-path)

Comment: @Rajesh I want to download file that is not in my project folder with my code. File is in my computer in different folder. Could I do that?

Comment: You have the server running on a Linux and are attempting to access a path that is only valid in Windows. This seems to imply that there are two machines that don't have a common filesystem and as such the Linux one can't access the filesystem of the Windows one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I need use just new URL(`file:${"c:/app/A"}`);
so it will be like that:

```
let filename = "someName.com"
let absPath = "c:/app/someName.com";
fs.writeFileSync(`${filename}`, fs.readFileSync(new URL(`file:${absPath}`)));
res.download(`${filename}`, `${filename}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `\\` as path delimiter for Windows (`c:\\app\\A`) and read about Node.js module "[path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html)".