# error when get html file by express js and javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I a beginner with Express js and when I reload the server to show the HTML file display "Cannot get" this is photo from the console and its show som errors
[image]

this my code server-side:
[image]

and this is a photo from git bash and the server is working[image: and this is a photo from git bash and the server is working]

and this is my HTML code
[image]

help, please

Comment: Try `app.get` instead of `app.route`. And use the `res` variable of the callback.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code. Copy and Paste it please.

Comment: For future reference, don't post screenshots of your code. Post the actual code as text. It will make it easier for others to copy and paste you code in order to help you.

Comment: ok  thanks verymuch

Comment: @AbdelilahZaidane were you able to fix it?

Comment: @ goto1 no still the same problem

Comment: @AbdelilahZaidane have a look at my answer.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463423/res-sendfile-absolute-path

You need to add 'public' to path to file

Comment: @AbdelilahZaidane are you still having issues?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `app.route()`, use `app.get()`
like this

```
const express = require("express)
const path =  require("path")
const app= express()
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'))
})
app.listen(3000,()=>{
 console.log("server running at port 3000")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`app.route` takes a string as an argument and returns a single route - you're passing a callback function, so change your route handling to the following:

```js
// use the appropriate HTTP verb
// since you're trying to serve the `index.html` file, 
// `get` should be used

app.route("/")
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html')
  })
```

Alternatively, you could just do the following:

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html')
})
```

Here's a working example:

```js
// thecodingtrain/
//   index.js
//   home.html
//   package.json

const path = require("path")
const express = express()

const app = express()
const PORT = 3000

app.route("/")
  .get((req, res, next) => {
     res.sendFile(
       path.join(__dirname, "./home.html")
     )
  })

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT})
})
```

Hope this helps.