# How to serve static files in express app without having to prepend __dirname

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Apologies for this question which may be seen as basic but I feel there must be an easy method for this for such a popular framework yet I am struggling to come across it.

I am wanting to serve page routes using a relative path.
i.e. `sendFile("/pages/index.html")`
but the only solution that works is using `sendFile(__dirname + "/pages/index.html")`

I have read posts which say to add `app.use(express.static("public"))` to serve static content but this only impacts get requests to the full URL from client not the sendFile() from server.

i.e. If client types http://...../pages/index.html it correctly returns but when they type http://...../ and I use sendFile("/pages/index.html") the route is incorrect.

Relevant chunks of code are below

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(express.static("public"))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200);
    res.sendFile("/pages/index.html")
});
```

Directory structure is public, public/css, public/js, public/pages.

Again all I'm trying to do is not have to write __dirname in every sendFile().
I feel like I'm missing something. Any suggestions are appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: I believe this might be your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52031283/9488284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Yasio linked https://stackoverflow.com/a/52031283/9488284 (Thank You).
The solution is to create a middleware function that prepends __dirname to every sendFile and then use that function instead of sendFile.

Like such

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.show = (name) => {
    res.sendFile(`/public/${name}`, {root: __dirname});
  };
  next();
});
```

You can then display pages (in my dir structure) using

```
app.get('/demo', (req, res) => {
  res.show("pages/index.html");
});
```

i.e. when someone requests http://.../ you will return to them pages/index.html.
This essentially means instead of using sendFile() use show() to return files.