# Signup page issue

Tags: html, node.js, server

when I click on signup it redirects me to folder C or C drive of my pc and shows that on chrome instead of sending information on my hyper terminal

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0bSy.png)

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj5zg.png)

Comment: Seems you're a new contributor, try including the code in your post or a GitHub link where it resides. It becomes difficult for people to actually go to image and replicate the logic.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463423/res-sendfile-absolute-path) the issue can be in your app.js as __dirname returns the directory that the currently executing script is in. In your case, it is C: drive. So provide absolute path first.