# Cannot open SSL Key File in Node server - ENOENT

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, grunt-build-control

I'm attempting to deploy a project I inherited to heroku using grunt buildcontrol for the first time. Though I am able to build and deploy, on running I get an error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'ssl/keys/server.key'

Checking the dist directory, indeed there is no ssl directory. Thusly, I've added it to /dist to no avail. Thinking that app.js inside of /dist/server/ might be scoped to that directory, I copied the ssl directory there - again the same issue. Inside of /dist/server/app.js:

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/keys/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/keys/server.crt')
};

// Setup server
var app = express();
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app);
```

Where is it going to look for the ssl directory if not inside the server folder?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `readFileSync` function [evaluates relative paths to the current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8131696/2646526) of the node executable, which on Heroku is `/app`, not the dist folder.  To access your dist folder as a relative path, you should be using [`path.resolve`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14594282/2646526):

```
var path = require('path');
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('dist/ssl/keys/server.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('dist/ssl/keys/server.crt'))
};
```

Alternatives include:

- `fs.readFileSync(__dirName + '/dist/ssl/keys/server.key')`
- `fs.readFileSync(process.cwd() + '/dist/ssl/keys/server.key')`
- `fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirName, 'dist', 'ssl', 'keys', 'server.key'))`

But I feel that `path.resolve` is right blend of concise and robust.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "__dirname" variable to access to the directory path of your app, if you have the app.js next to your dist folder where there is the /ssl/keys it will look like these:

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/dist/ssl/keys/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/dist/ssl/keys/server.crt')
};

// Setup server
var app = express();
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Thinking that app.js inside of /dist/server/ might be scoped to that directory, I copied the ssl directory there.

When you log `__dirname` in `app.js` you will get `/dist/server`.

You stored your `ssl` directory in `/dist/server`.

So, your `key` path is `/dist/server/ssl/keys/server.key` and your `cert` path is `/dist/server/ssl/keys/server.crt`

you code should be:

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/keys/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/keys/server.crt')
};
```

If you store `ssl` directory in `/dist`:

your `key` path is `/dist/ssl/keys/server.key` and your `cert` path is `/dist/ssl/keys/server.crt`

Now, your code should be:

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../ssl/keys/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../ssl/keys/server.crt')
};
```

I am using the same on one of my project and it works fine without using `path.resolve` or `path.join`. Even the `../` parent directory representation is resolved by `fs.readFileSync` itself.

Answer (score 0):

The readFileSync function needs a relative path so you can use the path module to get the relative path of the keys.

```
var path = require('path');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(path.resolve('.'), '/ssl/keys/server.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(path.resolve('.'), '/ssl/keys/server.crt'))
};
```