# How to point Node server to serve an index file 1 path up?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here is my folder structure:

I have everything inside the `src` folder, `src/index.html` is what I'm trying to point too. And my node server file is in `src/server/server.js`

[image]

When I run the correct `node src/server/server` command I get the following error:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.get('/category', (req, res) => {
    res.end('Categories');
});

app.listen(8999, (res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/leongaban/Projects/CompanyName/appName/src/server/index.html'

So the error message is telling me I need to go 1 more folder up, so figured something like the following:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('../index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

However now I get a Forbidden error:

> ForbiddenError: Forbidden

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you get a `Forbidden` error is because Node.js finds the relative path `../` malicious (for example if you get a file based on user input he might try to reach files on your file system which you don't want him to access).

so instead you should use the [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module like pointed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594121/express-res-sendfile-throwing-forbidden-error) question

Your code should use path like so:

```
var path = require('path');
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '../index.html'));
```

Comment: Thanks! :D I had to adjust my path slightly `'/../index.html'` but it works now! Hehe it's serving my index file, but without the Angular app running. So next step is figuring that out...

Comment: Glad you're making progress, be sure to mark one of the answers so users can easily use your question in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a mean stack problem earlier on.

Mor Paz' above answer should work. :)

Just to contribute, i did the following.

```
var path         = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile('../index.html');
});
```