# How to render static file not in public or view folder after middlware in express js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a folder

> api-docs inside that I have index.html some css and js file

I need to render api-doc for authenticated user.

I am not using it in views as In project I am using jade in view and api-doc is in html

I have tried

```
router.get('/v1/secure-api-documentation',(req,res)=>{
     console.log('A')
     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/../api-doc/index.html');
 });
```

and

```
router.get('/v1/secure-api-documentation',ensureAuthenticate,(req,res)=>{     
     express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../api-doc'))
 });
```

Comment: What is the issue with `res.sendFile` ?

Comment: @Rayon getting Forbidden, is it because folder access ?

Comment: I would suggest you to check the path which is being formed in `__dirname + '/../api-doc/index.html'` in `console`

Comment: path is fine but Getting "forbidden" in response

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14594282/1746830 Give it a try..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

express.static(path, [options]) returns a function. So basically what your code is doing is :

```
router.get('/v1/secure-api-documentation',ensureAuthenticate,(req,res)=>{
    express_static_function // this function further accepts arguments req, res, next
    //there is no function call happening here, so this is basically useless
 });
```

However, this is not what express.static is used for
What express.static does is, takes the request path and looks for a file with the same name in the folder you specified.

Basically, if a GET request comes to *'/v1/secure-api-documentation'*, it will take the request path after *'/v1/secure-api-documentation'* and look for that inside **api_docs** folder. 
Passing express.static to router.get() will call it for the very SPECIFIC path. This is important.
GET *'/v1/secure-api-documentation/index.html'* will fail. Because such a route is not handled.

What you need to do this is call express static for any path like *'/v1/secure-api-documentation/*'*.

For this you need to take the express app object, and write the following code:

```
//make sure to use the change the second argument of path.join based on the file where your express app object is in.
app.use('/v1/secure-api-documentation',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../api-doc')));
```

This will now work for not only the index.html file but any js/css file inside api_docs that is requested.